# Bind String ( text ) paste to key ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Google didn't gave me an answer for this , so i'm asking here.

Is there a way to bind a text ( some characters ) to a key ( lets say F1 ) so that when i press the key is like i typed those characters ?

For example , i have some work-related accounts with some creepy passwords that are VERY hard to remember. I just go to login page , enter username , click on the password field , press F1 and the password is wrriten.

I hope you understand my question... I find this pretty usefull for general purphose , i bet there are a lot more guys wondering how to do this.

Thank you ,

G. V.

Comment: What desktop do you use? GNOME?

Answer (score 0):

Many terminal emulators allow it. For instance, with xterm, it's done via resources:

You can place resources on the command line in a file loaded by xterm such as .Xdefaults-$HOST (see also $XAPPLRESDIR, $XUSERFILESEARCHPATH, $XENVIRONMENT), or by installing them in the X server with xrdb (which has the advantage that every xterm connecting to your X server from any host will get it, but which means anybody able to connect to your X server will be able to get it)

On the command line:

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations: #override <KeyPress> F1: string("whatever")'
```

Beware though that anybody who runs "ps" on the machine will be able to see that "whatever".

For a terminal independent solution, you can use GNU screen, and have something like this in your .screenrc:

```
bindkey -k k1 stuff "whatever"
```

**EDIT**. Sorry, reading your question again, I see you're not using a terminal, so only look below, though the above could be useful to others. If it's in a browser, also look at add-ons designed for that.

Now, if you're looking for a non-terminal solution, you can look at "xte" (from xautomation) to generate KeyPress and KeyRelease events and configure your window manager to run a script that does:

```
xte key\ {w,h,a,t,e,v,e,r}
```

upon pressing F1.

Whatever, you do, please consider the security implications of storing your password on the FS, or how it may be accessed.

See also solutions like keepass.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your quick response. Even tho what you say is a correct response to my question it doesn't help me. I'm too dum to now how to make gnome run that command when lets say "Control_R+F1" is pressed. Can you please be more specific in your answer ? I'm currently searching google how to do that , no luck yet. THANK YOU